# Ruby method with few or zero parameters - how to do it?

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments, reverse

I have two methods in Ruby:

```
def reverse(first,second)
   @items[first..second]=@items[first..second].reverse 
end
```

And:

```
def reverse
  @items.reverse! 
end
```

Can I combine these into one function and use an `if first.nil? && second.nil?` condition, or it is better to keep it like it is?

Comment: Can you tell me what your expectation or what do you want to see?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First option is to use default valued parameters:

```
def reverse(first = nil, second = nil)
  if first && second
    @items[first..second]=@items[first..second].reverse
  else
    @items.reverse! 
  end
end
```

The second option is to use variable number of args:

```
def reverse(*args)
  if args.length == 2
    @items[args.first..args.last]=@items[args.first..args.last].reverse
  else
    @items.reverse! 
  end
end
```